# Is there any solution for OnTick patched?

Tags: javascript

I Had a problem on the script that when I enter the game it told me:

> " Error message: patchOnTick was not successful "

So this is the if there any solutions I hope you comment below
The script for this game `https://krunker.io/`

This is the script `https://pastebin.com/raw/ucUT0mdC`

Answer (score 0):

Quick Answer:

The Game hack has been since patched.

Please do not hack in Kr***ker or any other games.

Thank you :D